# SQL Query - count - max

Tags: sql, join, count, max

I cant manage to come up with a query for a problem. I have three tables

```
CREATE TABLE institute (
    iid INT PRIMARY KEY,
    sign VARCHAR(127) UNIQUE, 
    city VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL,
    area INT CHECK (area>0));

CREATE TABLE desease (
    did INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(127) UNIQUE,
    level INT CHECK (level>0));

CREATE TABLE studies (
    did INT,
    iid INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (did) REFERENCES desease (did),
    FOREIGN KEY (iid) REFERENCES institute (iid),
    PRIMARY KEY (iid,did));
```

My question is: What are the names of the deseases by the largest number of institutes from Lisbon (Lisbon beeng the `city` from `institute`). This is what i came up with but it doesnt give me the right answer.

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.name, MAX(I.iid)
  FROM desease D, studies S
  JOIN institute I ON (S.iid = I.iid)
 WHERE I.city = 'Lisboa' AND D.did = S.did
 GROUP BY D.nome
HAVING COUNT(I.iid) = MAX(I.city)
```

As an example : Imagine 5 institutes al with city = 'Lisbon' and with iid A,B,C,D,E respectevely (just for demonstration purposes, I know type is INT); 5 Diseases with name = Z,X,N,V,M respectevely.

Now lets say desease Z,X, and M are studied by institutes A,B,C (in any order), desease N is studied by D(1 inst.) and desease V is studied by E (only one).    So the max number of deseases studied by any Lisbon institute is 3 (A,B and C all study 3 deseases) so the table would look like this

```
Z - 3
X - 3
M - 3
```

Edit : I managed to found a way to do it. Here is the query that I came up with

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.name, COUNT(*) AS C
FROM desease D, studies E, institute I
WHERE I.iid = E.iid AND D.did = E.did AND I.city = "Lisboa"
GROUP BY D.name
HAVING C >= ALL (
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM desease D, studies E, institute I
WHERE I.iid = E.iid AND D.did = E.did AND I.cidade = "Lisboa"
GROUP BY D.name
```

);

Comment: omg you need to tell how to do that I tought I would have had to do that but I didnt find where to do it

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/156331

Comment: Please rephrase your question. I didn't understand what exactly do You need.

Comment: An institute studies a desease. Imagine The institute from Lisbon that studies the most diseases. Make X this number of diseases. I need the names of the diseases that are beeing studied by X institutes from Lisbon. So Il get a table (D.name, X)

Comment: It would help if you included example data and the expected result.

Comment: Ok I think my second query does what you need.

Comment: You really do not need `DISTINCT` in your final query. Grouping by `D.name` makes the resulting rows distinct enough.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand structure/problme well enough but I did see that you were mixing joins and had a cross join which would inflate the number of recrds.

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.name, MAX(I.iid)
FROM desease D
INNER JOIN  studies S ON D.iid=S.Did
INNER JOIN  institute I ON (S.iid = I.iid)
WHERE I.city = 'Lisboa' AND D.did = S.did
GROUP BY D.nome
HAVING COUNT(I.iid) = MAX(I.city)
```

Comment: You have writen Lisboa instead of Lisbon. If your portuguese here is the question in portuguese : Quais os nomes das Doenças estudadas pelo maior número de Institutos de Lisboa?
Pretende-se uma lista com o nome da Doença e o n.º exacto de Institutos que estudam essa doença. (this is the exact questin I just translated it to english)

Comment: This looks to me like the right answer but it doesnt give me the correct results X( it has to be something close to this ... Il try experimenting a little

Answer (score 0):

Just a rough guess what you need:

```
SELECT stu.iid, COUNT(*) AS nstudies
FROM studies stu, institute ins
WHERE stu.iid=ins.iid
AND ins.city='Lisboa'
GROUP BY stu.iid
ORDER BY nstudies DESC;
```

This should give you a list of institutes that are in Lisboa and the number of studies they did.

```
SELECT stu.did, COUNT(*) AS ninst
FROM studies stu, institute ins, disease dis
WHERE stu.iid=ins.iid
AND stu.did=dis.did
AND ins.city='Lisboa'
GROUP BY stu.did
ORDER BY ninst DESC;
```

This gives you a list of deseases and the number of Lisboa instutitues that did it.

Unfortunately your question leaves a lot of room for speculation as to what you need -- maybe you should add some example data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

This would return a list of disease names that have an institute in Lisbon starting with the one with the greatest number of institutes in Lisbon and going down:

```
SELECT D.name, COUNT(*) as numberOfInstitutes
FROM desease D
INNER JOIN studies S ON D.did=S.did
INNER JOIN institute I ON (S.iid = I.iid)
WHERE I.city = 'Lisbon'
GROUP BY D.did
ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc
```

If you need only the one that has the most institutes and you need the rest of the columns from the desease table, you can do this (in Sql Server):

```
SELECT TOP 1 D.* 
FROM desease D
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT D.did, COUNT(*) as numberOfInstitutes
    FROM desease D
    INNER JOIN studies S ON D.did=S.did
    INNER JOIN institute I ON (S.iid = I.iid)
    WHERE I.city = 'Lisbon'
    GROUP BY D.did
) as tblCount on tblCount.did = D.did
ORDER BY numberOfInstitutes desc
```